# how to pass single digit to the next command

Tags: ansible

I am trying to pass the RHEL version to the next command, but I can not:

my script is below:

```
### To Create Repo File

    - name: Check for the presence of the DIR. below
      stat: path=/etc/yum.repos.d
      register: dir
    - shell: mkdir -p /etc/yum.repos.d
      when: not dir.stat.exists
    - name: To get the RHEL Release
      shell: cat /etc/redhat-release | awk '{ print $7 }' |cut -c1
      register: RH_REL
#
    - shell: touch /etc/yum.repos.d/patch.repo
    - shell: echo [RHEL-{{ RH_REL }}-2020_{{ WW }}-OS] > /etc/yum.repos.d/patch.repo
```

the output from debugging I am getting is below:

```
ok: [dmzpnet6.wellsfargo.net] => {
    "RH_REL.stdout": "7"
}
```

but I need only to get 6 or 7  in the output to pass that single-digit how I can do it or maybe I can use something else instead of "register"?

Thank you.

Michael

Comment: `"RH_REL.stdout": "7"` - `but I need only to get 6 or 7 in the output` => isn't that what you are getting ?

Comment: yes, but I need to get only:   7    without : RH_REL.stdout": "7

Comment: Moreover, please have a look at the documentation, more specifically the modules, namely [yum_repository](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_repository_module.html), [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html), [blockinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html), [file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html).... all of your above tasks can be replaced with idempotent calls to these.

Comment: So one more documentation: [debug module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html). Use the option `msg: "{{ RH_REL.stdout }}"`. But you don't need to get this from a register. `ansible_distribution_major_version` should have this for you if you gathered facts => https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"I need only to get 6 or 7 ... or maybe I can use something else instead of 'register'?"*

A: Yes. You might want to use the variable `ansible_distribution_major_version` created by the [setup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/setup_module.html#setup-gathers-facts-about-remote-hosts) module. It's not necessary to run it explicitly. The facts will be collected by default on start unless you ask to `gather_facts: false`. For example

```
- hosts: remote_hosts
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_distribution_major_version
    - shell: "echo {{ ansible_distribution_major_version }} > /tmp/my_ansible_test.txt"
```

See the content of the file `/tmp/my_ansible_test.txt` at `remote_hosts`.

Comment: it it going to get ansible version ?  I am looking for RedHat version

Comment: yes, I got it and getting the correct RHEL  6  or 7 version, so instead of redirecting it to the file and doing debug, how I can direct it into my command:

Comment: yes, it is working, thank you, but now instead of redirecting it into the file, how I can redirect  6   or   7   to my command:        - shell: echo [RHEL-{{ RH_REL }}-2020_{{ WW }}-OS] > /etc/yum.repos.d/patch.repo

Comment: Hello,  it is working, thank you very much for you great help.

Comment: You're welcome. The comments do not include any useful info and might be deleted. This would make the reading simpler for others. It's not personal. This is how SO works. See [Should “Thank you” comments be flagged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged). Delete the comments, please.